# If $R$ is a commutative ring and $\mathfrak N(R)$ is its nilradical, then $0$ is the only nilpotent element of $R/\mathfrak N(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

> Prove that if $R$ is a commutative ring and $\mathfrak N(R)$ is its nilradical, then $0$ is the only nilpotent element of $R/\mathfrak N(R)$

Hey, everyone. I'm having some doubts about the validity of my proof of the above. As a reminder, the nilradical $\mathfrak N(R)$ is the set of nilpotent elements of the ring $R$. Here was my attempt:

**PROOF**: Suppose towards a contradiction that $x+\mathfrak N(R)$ and $y+\mathfrak N(R)$ are *distinct* elements of $R/\mathfrak N(R)$. Then, for some least positive $m,n \in \mathbb N$, we have $[x+\mathfrak N(R)]^m = x^m + \mathfrak N(R) = \mathfrak N(R)$, and $[y+\mathfrak N(R)]^n = y^n + \mathfrak N(R) = \mathfrak N(R)$. Thus, we can see from this that $x^m\in\mathfrak N(R)$ and $y^n\in\mathfrak N(R)$.

Also note that $x^{mn}=0$ implies that $x\in\mathfrak N(R)$ since $mn\in\mathbb N$, and $y^{mn} = 0$ implies that $y\in\mathfrak N(R)$ since $mn\in\mathbb N$. So, $$\begin{align}x+\mathfrak N(R) = y+\mathfrak N(R) & \iff x-y\in\mathfrak N(R)\\ &\implies (x-y)^{mn}=0\\ &\implies (x-y)^{mn}(x-y)^{1-mn} = 0\\ &\implies x-y=0 \\ &\implies x=y.\end{align}$$ This means that $x$ and $y$ are actually the same, implying that the only element of $\mathfrak N(R/\mathfrak N(R))$ is $0$.

> **Questions:** is it valid to put the constraint that $m,n$ are the *least* positive integers such that $x^m=0$ and $y^n=0$? Would that imply that $(x-y)^{1-mn}$ is non-zero since $x,y$ are distinct?

Thanks for reading over my proof.

Comment: In order to prove what you want it is not necessary to consider two distinct elements. You already know there is one, zero, so just suppose there is another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking things.

If $(x+N)^n= 0+N$, then $x^n\in N$, and by definition of $N$, there exists an $m$ such that $(x^n)^m=0$.

Thus $x^{nm}=0$, and $x$ is nilpotent in $R$. So $x+N=0+N$ at the outset.

I skimmed the proof but I don't see how you're going to get $(x-y)^{1-mn}$ to be sensible. I think $1-mn$ is typically going to be negative, and the negative powers of $x-y$ aren't necessarily defined.

Comment: This is a case where following one's nose works well.

Comment: Okay, to make sure that I understand: since $x$ is arbitrary, and the coset $x+\mathfrak N(R) = \mathfrak N(R) = 0 + \mathfrak N(R)$, we know that $0 + \mathfrak N(R)$ is the only nilpotent element of $R/\mathfrak N(R)$, yes? I understand this may seem like restating what you wrote, but it's the arbitrary nature of $x$ being selected that shows this for any $x$ in $R$, correct?

Comment: Yes, $x+\mathfrak N(R)$ is an arbitrary element of $R/\mathfrak N(R)$, and I agree with what you wrote in your comment.  I don't like writing $\mathfrak N (R)$ and pretending it is a coset (although it is common practice) because I like to have all my cosets mention a representative. I feel like omitting the representative sometimes leads to misconceptions when people learn about quotient objects. (It encourages thinking of $0+\mathfrak N(R)$ as "$\{0+n\mid n\in\mathfrak N(R)\}$"